# Angular 2 и MS SQL Server

Tags: php, javascript, sql, angularjs

Доброго времени суток Делаю в Angular 2 первые шаги, всплыла задача чтения данных из базы под управлением MS SQL server 2008. Нагуглил две библиотеки - mssql и tedious, есть ли между ними какая-то принципиальная разница, что быстрее или непринципиально? Мне быстродействие играет большую роль. И еще вопрос - можно ли организовать работу с базой данных MS SQL server только в рамках JS или обязательно использование PHP дополнительно ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы похоже не дастаточо разобрались в вопросе:

Хотя, в теории работать с базой напрямую с браузера можно, если порт наружу выставить, но лучше так не делать(безопасность)! Т.е. с базой лучше работать через приложение на сервере.
Приложение на сервере может быть написанно на любом языке (PHP, Javascript(nodejs), Python, C#...). Можете выбрать какой нравиться. После выбора языка можно выбирать библиотеку для работы.

А браузер должен получать данные уже с серверного приложения. Например в JSON структуру серверного приложения сделайте REST (RESTfull) API например. Можно XML через SOAP... Websockets... Зависит от требований.

По скорости, нужно правильно структуру данных создать, индексы, запросы оптимизировать. Думаю в вашей ситуации надо сначало научиться, потом оптимизировать.

Понятие быстро у всех разное!

Comment: Спасибо, то есть для меня ситуация упрощается, раз все-таки логичнее задействовать PHP.